# ¿Cuál es el significado de "bn" luego de USD?

Tags: traducción, abreviaturas

Estoy revisando unos reportes financieros en inglés y me he encontrado con este texto:

> USD2,221.0**bn**

Pienso que *bn* es una abreviatura de *billions*, pero al buscar en internet el primero resultado que me aparece es [Current Account in USA](https://www.focus-economics.com/country-indicator/united-states/current-account-usd-bn).

¿Estoy en lo correcto con la interpretación del significado de que es abreviatura para **billones**? De ser así, el monto puesto anteriormente es una cifra exageradamente elevada.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Esto no tiene nada que ver con el uso del español

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Significa billones: el [manual de estilo del *Daily Telegraph*](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/topics/about-us/style-book/1435301/Telegraph-style-book-numbers-measures-and-money.html), por ejemplo, indica que en ese medio se escriba "bn" en los titulares.

El [billón anglosajón](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill%C3%B3n#El_bill.C3.B3n_anglosaj.C3.B3n) equivale a mil millones de los que se usan en Europa, por lo que la cifra que citas es bastante más factible.